# What is the difference between 1) given any , 2 ) for every 3) for all in definitions?

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a lot of confusion.

Definition:

> A sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points in a metric space is said to converge
>   if there is a point $p \in S$ with the following property:  For every
>   $\epsilon> 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $d(x_n, p) < \epsilon$
>   whenever $n \geq N$.

What if we write:

1) Given $\epsilon> 0$, there exists an integer $N$.

2) For all $\epsilon> 0$, there exists an integer $N$.

Would it make any difference?

Comment: None. It's usually  to avoid repetitions, considered as bad style.

Comment: Notice, the "whenever" is yet another form of $\forall$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't, they are different words but they express the same thing. To convince yourself, prove the equivalences between the 3 propositions (for e.g. 1 => 2 => 3 => 1), but they are trivial.

Read about [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) if you want. Those 3 propositions, translated to predicate logic, are equal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Mathematically, they are three different ways of denoting the $\forall$ quantifier.